# Reset ajax form submition, so that new info can be sent again

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is a popup Form, I want to use, the issue is after the form is submited once, it does not show again to send different info, the only way it works is to reload the page, but i dont want to do that.

[here's the website](http://designwoop.com/2012/07/tutorial-coding-a-jquery-popup-modal-contact-form/)

[here's the live demo](http://designwoop.com/labs/model-contact-form/)

```
   <!-- basic fancybox setup -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|         (\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-  zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


    $("#send").on("click", function(){
        var emailval  = $("#email").val();
        var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(msglen < 4) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(msglen >= 4){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                        data == "true"; 
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On model box anchor link click write below code.

```
$('#contact').show().prev('p').hide();
```

So complete code would be

```
$('.modalbox').click(function(){
   //$('#contact').show().prev('p').hide();
   $('#contact').prev('p').hide();
   $('#contact').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding form with code:

```
$("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
  $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
  setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
}
```

So instead of it you should add new div with ID eg. `result` and show sending results there.

```
$("#result").html("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
```